# lodash dynamic filter with multicheck

Tags: javascript, lodash

I have a Multi check. I need a filter show with one option, two options, or three options.

This is the option:

[image]

The component has an array. The array is dynamic:

```
0: "Active"
​
1: "Inactive"
​
2: "Terminated"
```

Then for the filter, I use `lodash` inside for

```
for(var i = 0; i < dataFilter.length; i++) 
          {
              console.log(dataFilter[i]);
              const results = _.filter(res, function(item) {
                 return (item.project === dataFilter[i]);
              });
              this.items = results;
          }
```

This is the example `res`

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "createdOn": "2020-05-01T23:10:13.000Z",
    "createdBy": 'Juan',
    "Title": "testing",
    "project": "Active",
  }
```

Example the `dataFilter`

```
Array [ "Active", "Inactive" ]
```

But always replace and the filter just filter for one option but sometimes need show filter for 2 o 3 options.

`Lodash` has another way to the filter in this case or Maybe have another idea?

Comment: Please, give a specific example of `dataFilter` and `res` arrays, and example of the desired result.

Comment: @ΔO'deltazero' Now I wrote the example

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iterate through each item in the res array. Get the project name. Then check if that project name exists in the dataFilter. If it doesn't then remove that item - Like this:

```
this.items = res.filter(({ project }) => dataFilter.includes(project))
```

ES6 provides an inbuilt `.filter` function for arrays so there is no need to use lodash.

#### Basic example

```js
let products = [
  { brand: "Samsung", name: 'Samsung S22 Ultra' },
  { brand: "Apple",  name: 'iPhone 12 Mini' },
  { brand: "Samsung",  name: 'Samsung S21' },
  { brand: "Apple",  name: 'iPhone SE' },
  { brand: "Apple",  name: 'iPhone 13 Pro Max' },
  { brand: "LG",  name: 'LG V60' }
];

let brands_filter = ["Samsung", "LG"];

let filter_list = products.filter(( product ) => {
  return brands_filter.includes(product.brand)
})

console.log(filter_list);
```

Comment: I don't understand. How I should will make the loop?

Comment: .filter makes the loop for you. You can replace all of your code in your question and use this instead and it should work.

Comment: No, I replace my code but don't work. This is the error: "dataFilter.includes is not a function" DafaFilter in my code is an Array

Comment: This should not be possible if dataFilter is an array. If you console.log(dataFilter) is it  defined?

Comment: Maybe if you post a jsfiddle with more of the code then I can see what is going wrong (doesn't have to compile).

Comment: Yes, my dataFilter is an Array, This is the Array: [ "Active", "Inactive" ] , depends on check or The Array could be [ "Active" ] or [ "Active", "Inactive", "Terminated" ] ..... After I could be post the code in jsfiddle

Comment: This is the code: https://jsfiddle.net/juanitourquiza/ko5n0js1/11/

Answer (score 0):

### loadsh

One more idea is the to use [_filter iterator](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#filter) and custom function with nested loop (For each `dataFilter` check if the value [__includes](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#includes) on "this" item). If "true" return this item under the outer loop.

Example - **[Samsung, Apple, LG]**:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>

<script>
var products = [
  { brand: "Samsung", name: 'Samsung S22 Ultra' },
  { brand: "Apple",  name: 'iPhone 12 Mini' },
  { brand: "Samsung",  name: 'Samsung S21' },
  { brand: "Apple",  name: 'iPhone SE' },
  { brand: "Apple",  name: 'iPhone 13 Pro Max' },
  { brand: "LG",  name: 'LG V60' }
];

let brands = [
  { label: 'Samsung', facet: 'brand' },
  { label: 'Apple', facet: 'brand' },
  { label: 'LG', facet: 'brand' }
];

var brand_list = _.map(brands, 'label'); /* [Samsung, Apple, LG] */

var multi_filters = _.filter(products, function(product) { 
  let this_product_status = false;
  /* Nested loop throw list of brands */
  brand_list.forEach((values,keys)=>{
    /* Lodash Checks if value is in collection */
    if(_.includes(product.brand, brand_list[keys])){
      document.write("— " + product.name+"<br>")
      this_product_status = true;
    }
  })
  return this_product_status; /* if truthy return element */
}); 

console.log(multi_filters)

</script>
```

Same code - Example - **[Samsung, LG]**:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>

<script>
var products = [
  { brand: "Samsung", name: 'Samsung S22 Ultra' },
  { brand: "Apple",  name: 'iPhone 12 Mini' },
  { brand: "Samsung",  name: 'Samsung S21' },
  { brand: "Apple",  name: 'iPhone SE' },
  { brand: "Apple",  name: 'iPhone 13 Pro Max' },
  { brand: "LG",  name: 'LG V60' }
];

let brands = [
  { label: 'Samsung', facet: 'brand' },
  //{ label: 'Apple', facet: 'brand' },
  { label: 'LG', facet: 'brand' }
];

var brand_list = _.map(brands, 'label'); /* [Samsung, Apple, LG] */

var multi_filters = _.filter(products, function(product) { 
  let this_product_status = false;
  /* Nested loop throw list of brands */
  brand_list.forEach((values,keys)=>{
    /* Lodash Checks if value is in collection */
    if(_.includes(product.brand, brand_list[keys])){
      document.write("— " + product.name+"<br>")
      this_product_status = true;
    }
  })
  return this_product_status; /* if truthy return element */
}); 

console.log(multi_filters)

</script>
```